# Loading .bak (SQL Server Backup file) to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a scenario to load SQL Server backup file into a snowflake table. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Not without restoring the backup to SQLServer and then either exporting the table to a format Snowflake can import or using an ETL tool